# Snipcart, customising the cart

Tags: snipcart

Is it possible to customise say the colour of the button on the snipcart checkout? Or the font family?

I looked at some tutorials but they seem to be for an old version

Answer (score 1):

The same approaches to customize the cart can be used for the V3 [and more](https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/setup/customization).

In your case, you can change colors and fonts by **overriding the CSS**.

To do this, add a separate CSS file after the one provided by Snipcart with your own CSS rules targeting the same selectors.